# Multiple domains redirect to one site with different settings

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, dns

I have an asp.net webforms application that I want to be shared to multiple customers from different domains. Each domain should redirect to my main domain and keep its name at the address. My application should change its css settings according to the initial domain request.

I have done the redirection and the css handle but I am unable to determine the initial domain name, thus the default theme is displayed.

How can I determine the initial domain?

Here is my code befind:

```
If Page.Request.Url.Host.ToUpper = "secondDomain.com".ToUpper Then
    customCss.Href = "css/secondDomain.css"
Else
    customCss.Href = "css/default.css"
End If
```

for testing purposes I have also added:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "myAlert", 
                                    "alert(""" & Page, Me.Page.GetType, "myAlert", "alert(""" & 
                                               Page.Request.Url.Host.ToUpper & " - " & 
                                               Page.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost & " - " &
                                               Page.Request.Url.OriginalString & " - " &
                                               Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & """);",
                                      True)
```

I am getting always the main domain and not the initial.

at markup I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" runat ="server" id="customCss" />
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone might concern...I have made a work around with url rewrite. I have added "/theme/secondDomain" at the redirect url and convert it to theme=secondDomain.

Thus, now I am checking the QueryString and changing the css accordingly...